# How do I get Geolocation API co-ordinates out of my nested function and into React state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, geolocation

I'm trying to get a user's location using the [Geolocation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation_API) when a user clicks a button:

`<button onClick={this.setNewLatLong()}>"Use my location"</button>;`

I can access the lat/long coordinates with the following code:

```
setNewLatLong = () => { 
 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(displayLocationInfo);

  function displayLocationInfo(position) {
      const longitude = position.coords.longitude;
      const latitude = position.coords.latitude;

      console.log(`long: ${longitude} | lat: ${latitude}`);
  }
}
```

But I can't get the data into my state because the `latitude` and `longitude` variables are too nested within functions.

How can I get this data into my state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every component state update in React should be done with `setState()`. 
For your case, you can use `setState()` in the callback function passed into `getCurrentPosition()`.

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
    this.setState({
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude
    });
})
```

I would also recommend looking into using [React hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) for state (after you have finished learning the basics of React)

Answer (score 0):

In React, you hold on the information in the component's state. You can set the state like so:

```
this.setState({
  lon: longitude,
  lat: latitude
})
```

And access the state from your view (render function), or any where else you may need it.

Comment: When I use `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => position.coords.longitude)` as the state it returns "undefined" do you know why that is?

Comment: You need permissions to access position. If you dont have that, the set value will be undefined